# How to track the number of mp4 views?

Tags: video, web, media, mp4

We have an mp4 hosted up on an apache server that we would like to track the view count on.  Have googled and searched here quite a bit and haven't found any helpful info.  Looking for any helpful info on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the mp4 embedded on a website? If so just use google analytics.

You can set up goal conversions which lets you know how many times a specific action has occurred on your site. Such as the video being viewed.

There is a guide here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en

Comment: This link (2 steps deeper) may be more useful: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068